# How to I get the full form object from jsp into java by using serializeform and httpServletrequest

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, serialization

in my web page, I have one form's object but its size is big. so I get this object value is null in java. How can I resolve this issue?

Please help me.

**Here my code:**

- In JSP

  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: PFM_CONTEXT_PATH+"/MINE/CAL.cl",
      data: serializeForm("myForm"),
      success: function(data) {
         // do something
      }
  });
- In JAVA

  Object obj = httprequest.getParameter("myObj");// myObj is one of the parameter in myForm. 
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(obj); //  I got null pointer exception in this code

.

In my guess myObj Object size is big.

Comment: what effect do you want?

Comment: form's object is very big so it returns null in my java class. this is my problem. let you help me?

Comment: how big is **big**?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @ Scary Wombat  Please find my code.

Comment: If you got a NPE on the code you showed then it means that `httprequest` is `null`

Comment: @ScaryWombat please find the correct code sorry for the mistake.

Comment: what json library are you using?

Comment: I don't know the exact version of json.jar but this size is 43KB.

Comment: GSON ? Jackson ? Other ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think this is not JSON jar issue. individually I retrieve the object obj it was null.

Comment: well in that case maybe it is not in the `form` that your are `POST`ing